# When do I need to use "para" before an infinitive vs. just using the infinitive?

Tags: infinitivo

For example, if I wanted to say "It's horrible to hear that" would I say "Es horrible *para* oír eso" or "Es horrible oír eso"? And why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct answer is ***Es horrible oír eso***.

In English you have always *to* in infinitive, but in Spanish you just use the verb in its basic form, ending in ***ar***, ***er*** or ***ir*** (without ***para*** or anything else).

When you use ***para*** is when you want to say ***to*** but not because it is an infinitive, but because there is purpose. For example ***I come here to see my brother***, that means ***Vengo aquí para ver a mi hermano***, the word ***para*** specifies why you came here.

Note that this is only a clue for you to understand, you cannot always translate ***para*** as ***to*** or vice-versa.

Comment: It might be useful to add that any Es + adjective would work as you explained. "Es bonito oír esto". "Es raro pedir aquello". Put +1 anyway. :)

Comment: +1. Re: "because there is causality": I'd suggest "purpose" rather than "causality". Also, if you're going to explain when to use *para* + infinitive, then another case that probably bears mention is "demasiado <adjective/adverb> para <infinitive>", "suficientemente <adjective/adverb> para <infinitive>", etc.

Comment: Preceding the Spanish verb with "para" is like preceding the English verb with "in order to" instead of using a bare infinitive.

Comment: "In English you have always to in infinitive": this is not entirely true. In English there is also the bare infinitive, without "to", and in Spanish that will also be translated as infinitive, e.g. Let it be: Déjalo ser / I made him come: Lo hice venir / I heard him shout: Lo oí gritar.

Answer (score 4):

In English, a "to"-infinitive can be used, among other functions, (1) to introduce the subject of the sentence or (2) to introduce an adverbial of purpose.

In the sentence proposed:

- It's horrible to hear that.

"to hear that" is the subject of the sentence. Notice that, though less idiomatic, you can say:

- To hear that is horrible.

If that is the case, the Spanish form will be the infinitive:

(1) Es horrible oír eso (= Oír eso es horrible).

Instead, if the "to"-infinitive can be replaced with "for (the purpose of) V-ing" in English, then it is an adverbial of purpose and "para" + infinitive will be required in Spanish:

- This radio station is horrible to hear the news (= for the purpose of hearing the news).

(2) Esta radio es horrible PARA oír las noticias.